# Symfony site on Azure with ClearDB connection

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, azure, cleardb

I have an Azure Web App with a Symfony site installed and a separate Azure MySQL ClearDB. I can connect from my local computer to ClearDB using a MySql client but I can't manage to make connection from Symfony even though the connection details are identical. Anyone had this issue and knows how to get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this.

Maybe you could [clear cache](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-cache-clear-with-warmup) after editing `parameters.yml` file by running the following command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env={dev|prod}
```

Comment: Silly me. "If you have a problem, always try clear the cache first!" Thanks man :-)